# Customizing the New Item Form Controls

Tags: calendar, custom, field-controls

I need to, for a calendar control of a date field in the new item form, make only the current day and the day after it to be the only selectable dates in that control. Of course, this changes daily or in other words the next day the selectable dates will change according to the current date (dynamically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to write a custom control to make that happen.  Another approach could be to change the value after selection with javascript/jQuery.  For example, change the date to Today for anything <= today, and tomorrow for anything > today.